# Что быстрее создать переменую или обратиться глобальной через указатель?

Tags: c++, указатели

Мир вам люди,

Ответьте на странненький вопрос пожалуйста:

Что быстрее: создать временную переменую или обратиться к глобальной через указатель?

Код пишется для Arduino и его компании.
Пишу протокол для связи по радио (433mhz FS1000a)
Скорость важна как нигде.
В частном случае речь идет о переменной `currentTime`.
Перефразирую вопрос, что процессор делает дольше: 
создает новую переменную `unsigned long` или же разыменовывает указатель?

Функция запускается по прерыванию смены статуса пина:
Была использована библиотека [PinChangeInterrupt](https://github.com/NicoHood/PinChangeInterrupt)

```
 void incrCounter(void)
    {
        counter++; //each change increments this var
        unsigned long currentTime;
        if (currentTime - lastTime < pulseTimeLimit)
            return;
        lastTime = currentTime;
    }
```

Comment: Создание переменных и разыменование указателей это термины языка высокого уровня. Процессор этим не занимается. Скорость зависит от того, как оптимизатор это все оформит, а это зависит от контекста и того, какой компилятор используется. В вашей ситуации может лучше всего просто потестить что быстрее. И да, если скорость важна как никогда, то может стоит использовать ассемблер.

Comment: По моим  сведениям, для указателя создается доп. ячейка содержащая адресс реальной переменной. А при обращении через указатель, (уже незнаю кто именно, я думал процессор) процессор вычисляет местоположение реальной переменной и вписывает изменения туда. Разве это не так?

Comment: А почему вам бы не протестировать для конкретно вашего компилятора? Каждый компилятор ведёт себя по-разному, нету универсальных, обязательных правил для всех компиляторов. Да что там, компилятор вообще имеет право выкинуть любую из переменных, если сможет/захочет. Поэтому наши советы, основанные на практике работы с другими компиляторами, вряд ли подойдут вам.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответы.
К сожалению, с аппаратными прерываниями особо не потестишь (я точно не умею ) там даже вывод на экран (к примеру timeduration) это катастрофично медленный процесс. Единственный эффект который, я мог бы заметить это лучшее качество обработки принятой команды, но от этого зависит столько факторов(расположение передатчика, число и мощность помех и тд.) что все улучшения можно отсечь как погрешность измерения, я так думаю.

Comment: @Faig, в таком случае может быть стоит сделать эмулятор трансивера, с которого вы могли бы загонять в арт-руину произвольные данные.

Comment: Великолепная идея! Спасибо большое, сразу видна разница между профессионалами и дилетантом(мною). P.S: на самом деле ардуино это только для широкой публики. Я пишу и код лично для себя и 
 планирую сделать библиотеку для Orange Pi(Raspberry Pi). Сам я планирую пользовать непосредственно чип ATMega от AVR. Arduino как отпуск на 3 дня, вроде бы и в отпуске, но никуда не поехал :))